# How to get Sharepoint ListItem on DriveItem with Microsoft Graph API c#

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, list-item, microsoft-graph

The newly added DriveItem object returns the listItem field as null, which means that the relationship between DriveItem and ListItem offered by Graph Api cannot be used.

I created new DriveItem:

```
var driveItemResult= await CreateGraphClient().Groups[_options.GroupId].Sites[_options.SiteId]
                        .Drives[_driveOptions.DriveId]
                        .Root
                        .Children
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(driveItem).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now I would like to update custom columns in it. I know this is possible if you get driveItem as listItem. So I would like to do this:

```
var listItem= await CreateGraphClient().Groups[_options.GroupId].Sites[_options.SiteId]
                        .Lists[_listOptions.ListTitle]
                        .Items[driveItemResultId]
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(driveItem).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But `driveItemResult.Id` returns Guid. I need Id as number to take Item from list. And driveItem has property listItem. So I thought I can get correct id if I take `driveItem.ListItem.Id` but `driveItem.ListItem` is always null.

Do you know what could caused this behavior or how to get correct id?

Comment: Can you please provide more details of your requirements?

Comment: Please add what you are trying to do..a code snippet will help..

Comment: I added part with code. I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list item through below code:

```
CreateGraphClient().Groups[_options.GroupId].Sites[_options.SiteId]
                    .Drives[_driveOptions.DriveId]
                    .Items[driveitemid]
                    .ListItem
                    .Request().GetAsync()
```

Listitem is a expand property of driveitem, by default it has not been initialized. so we need to request it again.

BR

Comment: Thank you for this question and answer. I had exactly the same issue and this was a life saver :)